# SQL-Injection + PDO_MySQL = Danger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, zend-framework

SQL-Injection + PDO_MySQL = Danger

• Traditionally MySQL allows only a single SQL query

> ext/mysql - stops multi-queries completely
> ext/mysli – has separate function mysql_multi_query()

• ATTENTION: PDO_MySQL doesn‘t have this limitation
• SQL injection in ZF Application using PDO_MySQL is more dangerous than in applications using the traditional MySQL interfaces.

How long this is true?
I read it [here](http://static.zend.com/topics/Webinar-Zend-Secure-Application-Development-with-the-Zend-Framework.pdf)

I read zf is very secure framework, but I didn't find anything inbuilt in that to secure db.

Comment: When you put citations in your question, please cite your sources.

Comment: I added a link for source.

Comment: A bulldozer can hurt you more badly than a shovel. That's okay as long as you don't let your kids drive it.

Comment: @PraveenD Can you precise what is lacking for you in the answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not relevant. An injection might be worse but you must simply not allow injections.

Never concatenate unverified inputs in strings to build SQL.

Always use prepared statements : they will prevent the breaking of your query into multiple queries.

When you do

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
```

there's no way for the value provider to break that query and do something's else than a `select` (example taken [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)).